# Read env variables in React bundled with Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, deployment, environment-variables

I have a Spring Boot application with a bundled React frontend. It's configured with maven frontend plugin to build the react app and put it in the `/static` so it is served by Spring Boot. Everything is wrapped in a single .jar and deployed to a k8s cluster where the env variables are being handled separately and read by the Spring Boot.

Now, I have to add an API key as a env variable to be read by the React frontend.

As far as I've figured, I can't use `.env` files since it's not an independent React deployment and won't be seen by the frontend. The only thing I can think of is to pass it to Spring Boot and then expose it via an endpoint to the frontend.

Am I missing something, is there a way to use `.env` files in this setup, or some other way that is better for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was eventually resolved by setting it as an environment variable for the Spring Boot application which then read that value and exposed it via a dedicated controller on a secured endpoint. The react app would then simply fetch it via a GET request from the controller.

Comment: thanks @Nikola Dragic for answer... could you please provide some sample code for this

Answer (score 0):

For those, who wonder how to pass variables from Spring to React, here is how I've done that.

1. In your Spring Boot app, create a web controller that will serve `index.html` generated by React:

```
    @Controller
    public class MyWebController {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index(Model model) throws Exception {
            model.addAttribute("ENV_VAR",
                    "MY_ENV_VAR");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

2. In your `index.html` (it's located in <react_folder>/public/index.html) add following line to head tag:

```
<head>
<script th:inline="javascript">window.ENV_VAR = /*[[${ENV_VAR}]]*/ undefined; 
</script>
</head>
```

Note, that if you're using minifier, it will delete comments by default. I.e. if you created react app using `create-react-app`, you should disable minifying for that lines like that:

```
<head>
<!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
<script th:inline="javascript">window.ENV_VAR = /*[[${ENV_VAR}]]*/ undefined;</script>
<!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
</head>
```

3. Then, you can access your env var in the app using `window.ENV_VAR`