# Access ENV variables from React App served by Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have a Spring Boot application with a bundled React frontend. It's configured with maven frontend plugin to build the react app and put it in the /public so it is served by Spring Boot. Everything is wrapped in a single .jar and deployed to a k8s cluster where the env variables are being handled separately and read by the Spring Boot.

I have seen other solutions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210557/read-env-variables-in-react-bundled-with-spring-boot) discuss creating an endpoint to expose ENV variables.

The issue is that I am serving web-components for runtime integration. So the URL of the backend is unknown to the frontend (depends on the environment). Normally, you would always call `http://localhost:8080` from the react app to access the spring boot controllers, but not in my case, since the web-components will be calling the spring boot endpoints from the host web-application.

How can access ENV variables directly from react code? Or can I from spring boot, save the ENV variables to the same directory where the react app lives and read that file somehow?

Comment: If the react bundle doesn't know enough on how to ask for variables you need to bake it in.  The variables you want (or URL it needs to fetch them) need to be available to the bundle, such as by hardcoding it or including a file it can import.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I am adding my solution here in case it helps someone.

## Base URL

If you need to have the BaseURL environment specific, you will not able to use the controller solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210557/read-env-variables-in-react-bundled-with-spring-boot). You will need to work it out in react, and once you have it then you can use the Spring Boot Controller solution to get the rest of the ENV variables

```js
import { isStringNotBlank } from '../utils/utils';

export const isAbsoluteUrl = (urlString?: string) =>
  urlString?.indexOf('http://') === 0 || urlString?.indexOf('https://') === 0;

const getHostBaseUrl = () => {
  const urlString = document.currentScript?.getAttribute('src');
  return isStringNotBlank(urlString) && isAbsoluteUrl(urlString)
    ? new URL(urlString).origin
    : '';
};

export interface RuntimeConfig {
  baseUrl: string;
}

export const config: RuntimeConfig = {
  baseUrl: `${getHostBaseUrl()}/api`,
} as const;

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('config', config);
```

## Explanation

Essentially, we get the URL of the current source (js file) and get the base URL from there. In my case, the base URL is enough to call the backend.

If that is not enough for you, maybe you can use it to workout in which environment your app is deployed (dev, test, acpt, prod) and lookup the correct baseURL (you will have to hardcode this mapping in react).

Once you have the base URL, you can call your Spring Boot application endpoint to fetch the ENV variables as described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210557/read-env-variables-in-react-bundled-with-spring-boot).